# Creating a dictionary of lists of lists from a table within text file

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract data from a table in a text file, creating a dictionary of list of lists. So far my code has a few problems. It is including the header and only including the last row of data. I only want the SAMPLE_ID,  GENE_ID, and FLAG. I am trying this with one file, but ultimately will need to do it for a whole folder of these text files. Please let me now how to do this correctly! Table:

| SAMPLE_ID | CHROM | Start | End | Gene Name | Gene ID | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B18-CDC_S1 | NC_000962.3 | 6571 | 6762 | gyrB | Rv0005 | No deletion |
| B18-CDC_S1 | NC_000962.3 | 7360 | 7583 | gyrA | Rv0006 | No deletion |
| B18-CDC_S1 | NC_000962.3 | 760307 | 761286 | rpoB | Rv0667 | No deletion |
| B18-CDC_S1 | NC_000962.3 | 778989 | 779487 | mmpR | Rv0678 | No deletion |
| B18-CDC_S1 | NC_000962.3 | 800808 | 801462 | rplC1 | Rv0701 | No deletion |
| B18-CDC_S1 | NC_000962.3 | 1461044 | 1461290 | atpE | Rv1305 | No deletion |
| B18-CDC_S1 | NC_000962.3 | 1473245 | 1473331 | rrs | MTB000019 | No deletion |
| B18-CDC_S1 | NC_000962.3 | 1473657 | 1476796 | rrl | MTB000020 | No deletion |
| B18-CDC_S1 | NC_000962.3 | 1673409 | 1674052 | fabG1 | Rv1483 | No deletion |
| B18-CDC_S1 | NC_000962.3 | 1674201 | 1675012 | inhA | Rv1484 | No deletion |
| B18-CDC_S1 | NC_000962.3 | 1917939 | 1918747 | tlyA | Rv1694 | No deletion |
| B18-CDC_S1 | NC_000962.3 | 2153888 | 2156112 | katG | Rv1908c | No deletion |
| B18-CDC_S1 | NC_000962.3 | 2288676 | 2289272 | pncA | Rv2043c | No deletion |
| B18-CDC_S1 | NC_000962.3 | 2714123 | 2715372 | eis | Rv2416c | No deletion |
| B18-CDC_S1 | NC_000962.3 | 2726093 | 2726194 | ahpC | Rv2428 | No deletion |
| B18-CDC_S1 | NC_000962.3 | 2859299 | 2860418 | pepQ | Rv2535c | No deletion |
| B18-CDC_S1 | NC_000962.3 | 4246586 | 4249653 | embB | Rv3795 | No deletion |
| B18-CDC_S1 | NC_000962.3 | 4326003 | 4327474 | ethA | Rv3854c | No deletion |

```
import csv 

values_dict = {}

with open('/data/TB/WA_dirty_prep_reports/WA0911399-WAPHL-M5130-230329_S17_target_region_coverage.txt') as csv_file:
    for row in csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = '\t'):
        values_dict[row[0]] = row[1:]

print(values_dict)
```

results in this dictionary:

```
{'SAMPLE_ID': ['CHROM', 'Start', 'End', 'Gene Name', 'Gene ID', 'Flag'], 'WA0911399-WAPHL-M5130-230329_S17': ['NC_000962.3', '4326003', '4327474', 'ethA', 'Rv3854c', 'No deletion']}
```

I also tried this:

```
values_dict = {}

file = open('/data/TB/WA_dirty_prep_reports/WA0911399-WAPHL-M5130-230329_S17_target_region_coverage.txt')

for line in file:
    
    s = line.split()
    sample_ID = s[0]
    gene_name = s[4] 
    flag = s[7]

    values_dict[sample_ID] = [gene_name, flag]

print(values_dict)
```

which is problematic as well:

```
{'SAMPLE_ID': ['Gene', 'ID'], 'WA0911399-WAPHL-M5130-230329_S17': ['ethA', 'deletion']}
```

Comment: Use `defaultdict(list)` or `.setdefault(row[0], [])` to create a list of lists.

Comment: From your example outputs, it seems the problem comes from the parsing of the .txt file (separator side effects): where does the dict key 'WA0911399-WAPHL-M5130-230329_S17' come from; and see how you get `'SAMPLE_ID': ['Gene', 'ID']` instead of `'SAMPLE_ID': ['Gene Name', 'Flag']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not creating a list of lists, you're just assiging a list to the dictionary element, which overwrites the previous one.

Use `.setdefault()` or `defaultdict()` to create the list, then append your new row to it.

```
with open('/data/TB/WA_dirty_prep_reports/WA0911399-WAPHL-M5130-230329_S17_target_region_coverage.txt') as csv_file:
    for row in csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = '\t'):
        values_dict.setdefault(row[0], []).append([row[4], row[6]])
```

Comment: thank you this is a step forward! would like to extract data from just three of the columns. sampleID, Gene Name, Flag

Comment: So just select those columns instead of the slice. I've updated the answer.

Comment: ah yea this is what I have been trying but there is a syntax error!

Comment: Sorry, had an extra `[`

Comment: that still doesn't work. I also tried .append(row[4], row[7])

Comment: That's clearly wrong, `append()` only takes one argument. What error do you get with my code?

Comment: IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[46], line 7
      5 with open('/data/TB/WA_dirty_prep_reports/WA0911399-WAPHL-M5130-230329_S17_target_region_coverage.txt') as csv_file:
      6     for row in csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = '\t'):
----> 7         values_dict.setdefault(row[0], []).append([row[4], row[7]])
     10 print(values_dict)

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: You have some lines in the file that don't have the right number of fields. Are there blank lines in the file?

Comment: no it is just as you see in the table above. If I use a slice, say [4:] it selects everything appropriately

Comment: You only have 7 columns in the file. `s[7]` is column 8. Why do you have that in your code?

Comment: Flags is `row[6]`.

Comment: BTW, have you considered using Pandas?

Comment: oh jeez thank you for noticing that. Yes I am trying to learn the Pandas package as well! the end goal of this is to create these dictionaries for multiple text files (tables) and then add them to a dataframe